# Getting E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) everytime I update or install anything

Tags: nvidia, dpkg, dkms

I'm getting some kind of error related to an NVIDIA driver everytime I attempt an install/update via apt. For instance, see below (turned out g++ was already installed, but I get this for packages that are not present as well).

I recently had an issue with Ubuntu booting only to the terminal after an update. Seems it was trying to boot exclusively to a kernel version (I think 5.8?) in which the 340 driver is no longer supported. I have changed this so that I boot into a supported version. This is on a workplace machine with a legacy GPU/motherboard so upgrading isn't an option at the moment. I'd like to get rid of whatever messed up install is causing this problem, but I'm not sure where to begin. Any advice?

```
sudo apt-get install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2).
g++ set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up nvidia-340 (340.108-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-340
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-340-340.108 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  nvidia-340
Version: 340.108
Kernel:  5.4.0-58-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

nvidia.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia_uvm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 340.108
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-340-340.108 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-58-generic 5.8.0-36-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-58-generic
Done.

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 5.8.0-36-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-340.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-340/340.108/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-340 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-340 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-36-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-340
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Read, don't post, the file `/var/crash/nvidia-340.0.crash`. It's s text file, so any text reading tool works.

Comment: I'll update this with the contents when I'm at work next. I'm not knowledgeable enough about Linux to follow it myself. I already looked briefly at it. In the meantime I did find a discussion that seems to be related [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1872950).